# Anonymous functions in binary files

Tags: c++, function, lambda, anonymous

Do anonymous (lambda) functions get assigned some random/scrambled name in the binary files? Do they even appear in the binary files like normal functions do or how do they appear?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous function"? A function in an anonymous namespace? A lambda? Something else? (In any case, it depends on the compiler's ABI, but is typically done through name mangling).

Comment: There aren't generally *any* names in binaries. Machine code control transfer just consists of addresses.

Comment: @KerrekSB The final binary no but I'd expect names in the debug symbols and so probably in the intermediate object files (even if not properly exported) and if MSVC had separate compile and assemble steps it would have needed an identifier in that too.